# Alternative to fadeOut() to create pulse effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a recursive function like this to create a continuous pulsing effect on a div on my page and it's working. However, it looks like the `fadeOut()` removes the div element from the flow of the document and so the positions of some other elements on my page get shifted. Is there an alternative to this function providing the same functionality of a repeated pulse effect?

**Code**

```
(function pulse(){
            if(needStop) {
                needStop = false;
                return;
            }
        $('#player1,#score1').delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow',pulse);
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a plugin, here's a good one for jQuery:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/simple-pulse-plugin-for-jquery/

**Updated link:**

http://jsoverson.github.com/jquery.pulse.js/

Comment: Thanks but is this still available? The GitHub link says 'Page Not Found'.

Comment: No problem. :) If it solves your problem, please remember to check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try animating it's opacity.

```
$('#player1,#score1').delay(200).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 'slow', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#player1,#score1').delay(50).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 'slow', pulse );
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

You can use also CSS, maybe less code , this source is great:
http://daneden.me/animate/build/

all these effects can be applyed just adding and removing css classes